# $(document).ready() in a bundled script

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization

I've been doing a lot with web optimization recently, and I've come across an interesting problem. I was wondering if anyone might know of an existing solution.

Say you have multiple, page specific external .js files, each with it's own page specific
`$(document).ready()` function. Say the document ready function for page 1 applies a style to every `<li>` in the body, while the document ready in page 2 only styles `<input type="button" />`s. Just a simple example.

Now say you bundle these 2 scripts, along with all your library scripts, to reduce the number of http requests on page load. Now, both document ready's will fire, and the li's on page 2 will be formatted with the code meant only for page 1.

My question is this - Is there a way through either jQuery or a third party library to assign a specific document ready to a specific page but still have them all bundled into one .js file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an architectural point of view, if the block of code is only meaningful on one page, why shouldn't it be bundled with that page? I know it may seem more "organized" to put all of your HTML in one place and your javascript in another, but is it really saving your server or speeding up your user experience?

There comes a point with bundling when we reduce the number of connections, but increase the load on the server because we are stuffing so much unused junk into our combined file. Which is better serving 1,000 1k files or 100 100k files. If you have 100 pages each with a unique `document.ready` then you're adding *a lot* of data for a user when they only visit one page. The benefit of such a bundle is really only useful if there is a high probability the user will use some of the bundled content. Example would be Google.com, where they pre-cache entities needed in the results page, since by the very fact you are AT google.com implies with a pretty high degree of certainty you will do a search. It does *not* pre-cache gmail, or google docs though.

Comment: I like that analysis. However, the majority of apps most developers work on don't have nearly the width of the google app suite (I know it was just an example). So say you do have some page specific logic, but only a little per page. By paying the price on the first page visit, you speed up the load time for every other page visit.

Comment: This was a hard one, but I decide to accept this answer because of it's architectural analysis. I wish you could accept multiple answers

Answer (score 3):

I think you can use   [**jQuery(document).ready() - Wait Until Exists**](http://javascriptisawesome.blogspot.com/2011/07/faster-than-jquerydocumentready-wait.html)

Comment: Had not come across this before - very nifty.

Comment: I can see that being very useful

Answer (score 2):

I think there are conflicting goals in what you're trying to achieve: some of this stuff is common, and some of it specific to a single page. If it's the latter, why is it in the common module?

Having said that, one approach we have used successfully is to move all the commonly used functions into the main .js file, as well as the site-wide `$(document).ready()` stuff.

Individual pages may have a `localready()` function, and the last step of the `$(document).ready()` is to run this if it exists:

```
/* === common.js === */
$(document).ready(function(){
    // snip
    if (typeof(localready) != 'undefined') {
        localready();
    }
});
```

And in a nearby document:

```
</body>
<script>
    function localready() {
        foo();
        bar();
    }
</script>
</html>
```

So if the page being rendered has a localready() function, it gets called and does whatever it has to do. If it doesn't, the standard ready() has been executed, and that's that.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

You should bundle your scripts according to your pages.

Lets say your homepage needs jquery, and some custom scripts. Bundle them together and reference this bundle.

For other pages like the profile page you bundle required scripts and reference it.

Answer (score 0):

i guess a simple `if` could solve this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(location.href == page1) {
        ...
    }
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    if(location.href == page2) {
        ...
    }
});
```

---

### edit

if you don't wanna touch the code, you would like to don't include only the .js files that go on each page. This is even nicer because you are not wasting client resources on code he will not use.

An example of achieving this would create some kind of server code to glue all the files together, rather than doing it manually. An PHP example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo Glue::javascript($array_of_files); ?>"></script>
```

You could extend it to "glue" css or other type of files as you want. Also, you could  even include code to minify them as well. Of course the function would cache these files so it won't have to "glue" it every time.

Comment: Yea, I imagine that would be one solution. I was just hoping for something more at a framework level :)

Comment: well, i don't know if i understood it correctly but i edited the answer with a better solution that don't requires changing the javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

By "bundle" do you mean [suturing](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/suture/)?

One strategy I have seen, and partially implemented myself, is for the application to notify the view builder of all required CSS/JS as it constructs the view; In your example, as page one is being built, it would let the view builder know that it needs a particular JS file.

When the page is ready to be served, only one JS and one CSS file is referenced in the head, and they are sutured files.

I've seen it done just dynamically, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css?pageOne&specialFooter&member" />` or using a caching engine, e.g. `<link rel="stylesheet" href="995093293da7f03f9b631e8d3ec4efc7.css" />` (where that is actually a file that was generated the first time that combination of stylesheets was requested, and now is straight CSS [no longer dynamic])

Comment: I'm nervous of this approach because it all but prevents caching of CSS files since every page will likely have a different conglomeration of needed CSS components. Using `<style>` tags for CSS only relevant to the current page will always be faster than an external resource. Accessing multiple cached CSS files (or a few cached CSS files, and a smaller non-cached file) will be faster than a single sutured CSS file built for each page.

Answer (score 0):

You can always handle the page loading from an "application perspective".

For instance, create a "navigator object" that sets a constant when the user wants to navigate to a page:

```
const navigateTo = (page) => {
    let pageName = '?';
    switch (page) {
        case 'login.html':
            pageName = 'Login';
            break;
        case 'index.html':
            pageName = 'Home';
            break;
        default:
            console.log("Unknown page: " + page);
    }
    location.href = page;
    return pageName;
}
```

Transform your "document.ready" scripts into functions, for instance the Login page ready function:

```
$(function() {
   console.log( "Login page ready!" );
});
```

becomes:

```
const loginReady = () {
    console.log( "Login page ready!" );
}
```

Then, whenever the user changes page, by clicking a link or a navbar item, run a function like this:

```
const runReadyScripts = (page) => {
   switch (page) {
      case 'Login':
        loginReady();
        break;
      case 'Home':
        homeReady();
        break;
      default:
        console.log("Unknown page: " + page);
   }
};
```