# document.ready for multiple forms with single JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am referencing JavaScript as follows on an HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>    
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/application.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('document').ready(function() {   
// call some function specific to this page 
alert("this alert will only show for this particuar page");
});
</script>
```

My question is I have lot of functions especially bootstrap/jquery plugin functions to go inside document.ready(). As a result, there is lot of javascript code in all my html pages. How can I port all my functions that need to be executed inside document.ready to shared file application.js? I know that I can write a giant document.ready inside application.js to has all dom ready functions for all html files inside it. Is there any better option? Thank you for your help.

Edit:

Sorry if I was not clear. I was meaning to say: if there are two html pages: html1, html2 how do I tell my shared JavaScript file to execute document.ready functions for html1 and not for html2. If I understand it correctly, all functions inside document.ready will get executed every time a page loads.

Similar to my situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962456/document-ready-in-a-bundled-script)

Comment: UM, you can call document.ready in an external JS file and you can have multiple ready calls. What is the problem?

Comment: You should remove all `document.ready` wrappers, move the code to `application.js` and put this script before closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: check out http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear. I was meaning to say: if there are two html pages: html1, html2 how do I tell my shared javascript file to execute document.ready functions for html1 and not for html2. If I understand it correctly, all functions inside document.ready will get executed everytime a page loads.

Comment: Use different js files.  Have one file with your common js methods, and one file for each page that contains the page specific methods. Or, just put the page specific js in that html file.

Comment: FYI, there is no `document` dom node, `document` is a window object: `$(document).ready(...);` Even `$().ready(...);` would work, it is not always reliable

Answer (score 3):

The best idea would be to move all your JS to application.js, and let this find out on which page it is.

The most simple solution is to look at the URL of the current page:

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if(document.location.pathname.matches(/your-page\.html/)) {
          // do someting
    }
});
```

But a more elegant and reusable solution is to look for specific elements you want to interact with:

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var someSpecialElement = $('#some-special-element');
    if (someSpecialElement.length) {
          // do someting
    } 
    var someOtherSpecialElement = $('#some-other-special-element');
    if (someOtherSpecialElement.length) {
          // do someting
    } 
});
```

or…

```
// Shiny Javascript
(function(){
    const someSpecialElement = document.querySelector('#some-special-element');
    if (someSpecialElement.length) {
          // do someting
    } 
    const someOtherSpecialElement = document.querySelector('#some-other-special-element');
    if (someOtherSpecialElement.length) {
          // do someting
    }
})();
```

**Or** you can put classes on your body-Tag and test after the HTML has loaded

```
// jQuery
$(document).ready(function() {  
    var body = $('body');
    if (body.hasClass('edit-some-stuff')) {
          // do someting
    } 
    if (body.hasClass('delete-some-stuff')) {
          // do someting
    } 
});
```

or …

```
// Shiny Javascript
(function(){
    const body = document.querySelector('body');
    if (body.classList.contains('edit-some-stuff')) {
          // do someting
    } 
    if (body.classList.contains('delete-some-stuff')) {
          // do someting
    } 
})();
```

Comment: `$('document')` should be `$(document)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use script defer attribute, it will make all your scripts load AFTER html is renderer. So it's equal to put all scripts under document ready. Here is the link:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_script_defer.asp